# Como trazer para uma pagina JSP o conteúdo de uma consulta ao postgis?

Tags: html5, servlet, svg, java, postgis

Tenho o postgis com uma base de dados que eu baixei do ibge e preciso fazer uma aplicação em javaweb que leia o nome de um município e traga de volta os dados no formato  svg e exiba na tela a região passada como parâmetro.Como eu poderia fazer isso? Alguém poderia me indicar um tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve exportar seu mapa como um formato aberto que possa ser lido em Java, como [GeoJson](http://geojson.org/) ou [GML](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/gml). Você pode gerar o SVG no servidor. Para isto você pode transformar o GML em SVG (usando XSLT + java.xml.transform) e enviar para o cliente (embutido ou não em um HTML) ou enviar o GeoJSON para que o cliente construa o SVG (neste caso, em JavaScript, usando o [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) ou alguma biblioteca similar).

Apesar de serem formatos XML, a conversão de GML em SVG não é tão trivial (XSLT não é uma linguagem muito simples de usar, e a conversão de coordenadas em instruções de *path* SVG não é simples e pode haver perda de qualidade.)

Hoje em dia a solução mais popular é converter para *GeoJSON* e processar no cliente. Neste caso, você precisa exportar seu mapa (provavelmente arquivos no formato `*.SHP`) em *GeoJSON*. Se a sua versão do PostGIS não fizer isto, você pode baixar o QGIS mais recente, ou usar as [ferramentas GDAL/OGR](http://www.gdal.org/) que fazem isto em linha de comando ou em Java.

No cliente, você precisará desenhar o mapa. O D3.js oferece recursos para extrair propriedades do GeoJSON (como por exemplo, nome do município), projeções geográficas e várias funções que convertem polígonos GeoJSON em paths SVG, que são desenhados na tela e você poderá pintar e configurar usando CSS.

Este [tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) explica desde como converter SHP em GeoJSON até a criação de um mapa com D3.js. Ele também mostra como otimizar (já que arquivos GeoJSON costumam ser muito grandes) usando a biblioteca [Topojson.js](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson))

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção, vou conferir todos os llinks,   e futuramente, se eu não conseguir  resolver , eu coloco o meu código aqui, ai  você pode fazer uma analise.